# ERROR:Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in ***/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/__ivy_ngcc__/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build

Tags: angular9

I am trying to migrate my angular 8 code to angular 9.

I am seeing below errors when I started the server.

The update went fine.  Please give some suggestions on this error.

Thank you in advance!!

```
    ERROR in /Users/ert/Documents/file/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/__ivy_ngcc__/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/ert/Documents/file/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/__ivy_ngcc__/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build'
ERROR in /Users/ert/Documents/file/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/__ivy_ngcc__/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/ert/Documents/file/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/__ivy_ngcc__/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build'
ERROR in /Users/ert/Documents/file/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/__ivy_ngcc__/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/Users/ert/Documents/file/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/__ivy_ngcc__/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue while adding PDF Js library in Angular 8 project. You can add below code in `package.json` it will fix the error.

```
{
  "scripts": { },
  "dependencies": { },
  "devDependencies": { },

  "browser": {
     "fs": false
   }
}
```

Comment: I am just starting with Angular. Can you also please why this solves it ?